# How to HealthCheck on ECS without an ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have a Docker container(Spring Boot) that runs in an ECS cluster. We run it without Elastic Load Balancing.

We want to update the service without downtime, so when the new task is up and healthy, the old task stops. We have been trying to add a health check on the task definition, however it refuses to work. I have tried basic healthcheck commands.
But not work.